# I want to know whether it is possible to do Dynamic SQL in MATLAB R 2009b with Access database

Tags: sql, matlab, ms-access, dynamic

I want to know whether it is possible to do Dynamic SQL in MATLAB R2009b with an Access database. For example, is it possible to provide arguments for the field variables in the `WHERE` clause at run time. I have to check for 10 fields (F1,F2, ....,F10) with variables x(1),x(2),...,x(10) at run time., from a table `Stocks` in `MultiProductInventory` database. If it is possible what is the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is very basic functionality in any language. You will need a database connector (database toolbox usually works) and then you will create a query that has the dynamic fields built with a strcat function.

The section of the [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-access-odbc-windows.html) on the database toolbox provides step by step examples of this

Comment: I tried that, but the MATLAB is returning the error message " Undefined function 'fetch' for input arguments of type struct ". The same query, when i executed in static mode, in MATLAB  is returning the data without any error messages.